# Enemy Follows the Player Even His Death Animation Triggered

Tags: unity, c#

I have a 2D game project and I am coding but still on learning level. If I put simply, its based on player's escape and enemy follows to hurt him. Important case is, I am using A* PathFinding for this because there are obstacles for enemies and they need to pass them.(A stars pathfinding here: https://arongranberg.com/astar/ )

Problem is: Enemy following Player, wherever he goes on the flat rectangular scene, but when I kill enemy while following, his death animation triggered and he dies in 3 seconds but he still keeps following me while he is dying process going on and even when he is lying down on the ground. Simply flies to me.

What I need is to make him stop at that very location when his "isDead" parameter gets triggered. Because of A* using, I couldn't find a way to do it and override A* somehow.

Enemy has two scripts, one of them is the A* Path Finding script and the other is my Melee_Enemy which I use for animations, taking damage..etc kinda stuff. Melee_Enemy script is down below.This is the code I use for attack when close to player, and isDead function:

> ```
> public float stopDistance;
> private float attackTime;
> private bool isCloseForAttack;
> public float attackSpeed;
>
> public void Update()
> {
>     animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
>
>     if (player != null && !isDead)
>     {
>         if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > stopDistance)
>         {
>             animator.SetTrigger("isNotRunning");
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             animator.SetTrigger("isRunning");
>             if (Time.time >= attackTime)
>             {
>                 StartCoroutine(Attack());
>                 attackTime = Time.time + timeBetweenAttacks;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     IEnumerator Attack()
>     {
>         player.GetComponent<Player>().TakeDamage(damage);
>
>         Vector2 originalPosition = transform.position;
>         Vector2 targetPosition = player.position;
>
>         float percent = 0;
>         while (percent <= 1)
>
>
>             percent += Time.deltaTime * attackSpeed;
>         float formula = (-Mathf.Pow(percent, 2) + percent) * 4;
>         transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(originalPosition, targetPosition, formula);
>         animator.SetTrigger("attackMove");
>
>         yield return null;
>
>     }
> } }
> ```

@DMGregory

This is how I tried to disable the script:

On my Enemy, there are two scripts, one is the script I use for energy, taking damage.etc named "Melee_Enemy" which that is the script I shared in my post. Other script is the AI Pathfinder Script of the separate component I use. I want to disable second script by coding it in the first script. What I tried is:

On top I created

> public Component aiScript;

After Update() I used this:

> if(isDead)  {  Destroy(gameObject.GetComponent(aiScript));  }

But with this the code, unity has an error: aiScript cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Component' to 'System.Type'

Comment: Please show us your code where you move the enemy according to the A* pathfinding result. You should be able to check if the enemy is in a dead state there and skip the movement update.

Comment: I added to code in my post, this is my first post into this website and if I am doing something wrong here, sorry.

Comment: This looks like Unity code. Did you mean to tag your question [tag:unity]? There's nothing in here about the movement. Are you using a separate component like a NavMeshAgent for that? If so, did you try simply disabling or removing that component on death?

Comment: I edited my tag on the post with unity, and c#. The separate component I am using is A* PathFinding. Works like NavMeshAgent, maybe a little bit complicated but works well I think. And the simply disabling the component script on my enemy is just what I need. However, because I am newbie on coding, I am not sure how to destroy the script. I know how to destroy a component on conditions but it didn't work on script.

Comment: Show us the code for how you tried to disable this component, and how it failed to work.

Comment: On my Enemy, there are two scripts, one is the script I use for energy, taking damage.etc named "Melee_Enemy" which that is the script I shared in my post. Other script is the AI Pathfinder Script of the separate component I use. I want to disable second script by coding it in the first script. What I tried is:

On top I created

public Component aiScript;

After Update() I used this:

        if(isDead)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject.GetComponent(aiScript));
        }

Comment: And what went wrong when you tried that?

Comment: Btw I need to add, I dragged and dropped the script I want to disable on inspector component as I defined aiScript. So there is no problem about inspector.

Comment: But in the code, unity gave me error:
Destroy(gameObject.GetComponent(aiScript); code, it says: aiScript cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Component' to 'System.Type'

Comment: Sounds like you want Destroy(aiScript) with no GetComponent — aiScript already holds a Component, so there's no need to search for one.

Comment: And it worked, Thank you. I started with zero level to coding by researching and asking, I became little bit more experienced but sometimes the most simple things get out of hands. Again, I appreciate the help.

Comment: If that solved your problem, want to post your solution as an Answer below?

Comment: Thanks for help, I added for anyone needs to know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how I solve the problem is, with help of @DMGregory I defined on top of the Melee_Enemy script:

> public Component aiScript

I dragged and dropped my A* Pathfinding script to the inspector, the area I defined as aiScript component. After that I add another code after Update() function:

> ```
>     if(isDead)
>     {
>         Destroy(aiScript);
>     }
> ```

So by doing this, when Enemy's Death animation trigered with (isDead), following component simply disables itself. And this is how my problem came to a solution.